Why my Rust code is much slower than Python?
Here is recursive function written in Rust. It is aimed to search complex chemical reactions mechanisms using a DB. The core function of the code is here:
fn parse_database<'a >(
    db_object: &'a HashMap<&str, HashMap<&str,HashSet<&str>  > >,
    mechanism: &'a mut HashSet<&str>,
    reactants: &'a mut HashSet<&str>,
) -> (HashSet<String>, HashSet<String>) {
    let mut all_reactions: HashSet<&str> = db_object.keys().cloned().collect();
    all_reactions.retain(|r_id| !mechanism.contains(r_id));
    let mut found_reactants: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();
    let mut found_reactions: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();

    for r_id in all_reactions {
        let reactants_ = &mut db_object[&r_id]["reagents"].clone();
        if reactants_.is_subset(reactants) {
            println!("{:?}", reactants_);
            found_reactants.extend(db_object[&r_id]["products"].iter().cloned());
            found_reactions.insert(r_id);
        }
    }

    if !found_reactions.is_empty() {
        println!("go to next iteration");
        let next_itet_mechanism = &mut mechanism.union(&found_reactions).cloned().collect::<HashSet<_>>();
        let next_itet_reactants =  &mut reactants.union(&found_reactants).cloned().collect::<HashSet<_>>();
        return parse_database(
            db_object,
            next_itet_mechanism,
            next_itet_reactants
        );
    } else {
        println!("last iteration");
        println!("{:?}, {:?}", reactants, mechanism);
        return (
            reactants.iter().cloned().map(String::from).collect(),
            mechanism.iter().cloned().map(String::from).collect(),
        );
    }}
 
let mut mech: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();
 let mut reactants: HashSet<String> =... some task;

let reaction_db:HashMap<&str, HashMap<&str, HashMap<&str, HashSet<&str>>>> = ... some serde magic and convertion to &str

    //
    let (reactants, mechanism) = parse_database(
        &reaction_db[big_mech],
        &mut mech,
        &mut reactants,


and here is realisation in Py
def get_mechanism(big_mech, search_s):
    search_s = set(search_s)
    Data_for_matrix = dict()
    def parse_database(db_object : Dict, mechanism : Set, reactants : Set):
        all_reactions = set(db_object.keys())
        all_reactions.difference_update(mechanism) # removes all seen reactions from the search
    
        found_reactants = set()
        found_reactions = set()
        for r_id in all_reactions:
            reactants_ = set(db_object[r_id]['reagents'])
            reactants_ = filter_set(reactants_) 
            if reactants_.issubset(reactants):
                found_reactants.update(set(db_object[r_id]['products']))
                found_reactions.add(r_id)
                Data_for_matrix[int(r_id) ]=dict()
                Data_for_matrix[int(r_id) ]=[list(db_object[r_id]['products']),list(reactants_)  ] 
        if len(found_reactions) != 0:
            print('next iter')
            return parse_database(db_object=db_object, 
                                  mechanism=mechanism.union(found_reactions), 
                                  reactants=reactants.union(found_reactants))
        else:
            print('last iter')  
            return reactants, mechanism,  Data_for_matrix 

and it is 20 times faster then Rust version. I'm novice in Rust so any help would be appreciated.
I tried to use structure, like these
fn parse_database(
    db_object: &HashMap<String, Database>,
    mechanism: &mut HashSet<String>,
    reactants: &mut HashSet<String>,

) -> (HashSet<String>, HashSet<String>)

and tried most naive realisation with String not &str
parse_database<'a>(
        db_object: &HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Vec<String>  > >,
        mechanism: &mut HashSet<String>,
        reactants: &mut HashSet<String>,
        data_for_matrix: &mut HashMap<String, (Vec<String>, Vec<String>)>

there are some little difference in elapsed time of code but that was a little help.

Did you compile with cargo --release?

ChrisB, i used cargo run --release every time

Executing .clone() on a &HashSet reference will clone the entire hashset. You don't need to do that in the let reactants_ = ... line. Also please note printing on the console can also be time consuming.

This question is hard to answer. We don't know any of the characteristics of your data set, and we don't have a way of reproducing your measurements. If you made a mistake with your measurements, we have no way of figuring that out.

That said, Python does use more optimal algorithms for some of the operations. One example is all_reactions.difference_update(mechanism), which will always iterate over the smaller of the two sets, whereas all_reactions.retain(|r_id| !mechanism.contains(r_id)) iterates over what's probably the bigger of the two sets. The main issue are probably all the unnecessary allocations you are doing, which have already been pointed out. I suggest profiling the Rust code (try flamegraph-rs) to figure out where the bottleneck is.

It's hard to say without your dataset, but probably because of unneccessary clone()s all over the place.
Here is a slightly cleaned up version of the code:
pub fn parse_database<'a>(
    db_object: &'a HashMap<&str, HashMap<&str, HashSet<&str>>>,
    mechanism: &mut HashSet<&'a str>,
    reactants: &mut HashSet<&'a str>,
) {
    let mut found_reactants: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();
    let mut found_reactions: HashSet<&str> = HashSet::new();
    loop {
        for r_id in db_object.keys().filter(|r_id| !mechanism.contains(*r_id)) {
            if db_object[r_id]["reagents"].is_subset(&reactants) {
                found_reactants.extend(&db_object[r_id]["products"]);
                found_reactions.insert(r_id);
            }
        }
        if found_reactions.is_empty() {
            return;
        }
        mechanism.extend(&found_reactions);
        reactants.extend(&found_reactants);
        found_reactants.clear();
        found_reactions.clear();
    }
}


Since the function does not seem to need to manipulate any string, couldn't the returned hashsets be HashSet<&str> and skip all the string cloning?

@Masklinn: sure, I assumed OP had a reason for it, but you're probably right. Edited.

ChrisB, your answer is perfectly fine. Thank you!
I also followed one of the tips above and was amazed at how much printing intermediate results in my IDE RustRover worsens performance; removing prints gave a 10 times increase in performance. I’m not used to this when working with Python, where printing intermediate results slowed down the code by 10-30%, but not significantly. Now with all this improvements my Rust code  2 times faster then Py

@Juffin The set operations and dictionary look-ups for the Python code are written in optimized C code. If your data is big enough that the runtime is dominated by these operations, there just isn't much you can gain by using Rust. It's possible factor two is all you can get here, depending on your data. In other cases, you may get speedups by a factor of 1,000, or none at all.

@SvenMarnach: I wouldn't say that there isn't much to gain from Rust here. There's still quite a lot you could do here. The question becomes how much engineering effort is justified / you are willing to spent on optimizing this problem. Even just changing the hasher might already 2x perf here. Also, comparing the strings by value instead of pointer is totally uneccessary here. You could even roll a custom data structure and get a significant win. There are many optimizations left on the table that you simply couldn't do efficiently in python without writing C code.
